# Is Firestore event listener onEvent been called in sequence?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore `EventListener[QuerySnapshot]` interface, which I implement its `onEvent` method, and process its changes by `snapshot.getDocumentChanges`. The changes are `ADD`, `MODIFIED` and `REMOVE`.

One thing that is not clear to me is, will Firestore call my `onEvent` from multi-thread (I'm using Java API)? If true then I might have trouble. For example I first got `ADD` message, while it is still processing the `ADD` message, a new message of `MODIFY` came, then I have data non-consistence problem.

Does Firestore Java API do it in a multi-thread fashion then I have to take care of the multi-threading?

Comment: Are you using Android, or the Java server API?

Comment: @DougStevenson   Java server API, btw, I think I found the solution, when you add listener, you can specify an `Executor`, where if you use single thread executor, then you get events in sequence.

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that the callbacks without an executor are on different threads?  If not, and they are all on the same thread, then you can be sure that they happen in sequence.  Secondly, I'm not sure that passing an executor prevents your callbacks from happening concurrently, especially if your executor is backed by multiple threads.  If you are going to pass an executor, you should make sure it's only backed by a single thread.  In any event, the SDK is open source, so you can see for yourself what it does.  https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I tested, that in `onEvent` I print something then I just sleep forever, and in that case, if I change a document, I will get a new invocation, which proofs by default the executor is baked by thread pool. In java, there is a default executor that is baked by single thread, and I did test, that will block the invocation of the `onEvent` callback until the first one finished.